# Oracle Query not Successfully Run on PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Hi guys I have played around with Oracle SQL and PHP for only a short while so please forgive me if this sounds rookie. 
I got this query in my PHP codes to join 4 tables together, here's the query:

```
SELECT P.PTY_ID, 
       P.PTY_UNITNUM, 
        P.PTY_STREET, 
        P.PTY_POSTCODE, 
        P.PTY_SUBURB,  
       P.PTY_CITY,  
       T.P_TYPE_NAME,
       L.LIST_PRICE, 
       L.SALE_PRICE,
       C.SELLER_FNAME,
       C.SELLER_LNAME, 
       L.AVAILABILITY
    FROM PROPERTY_TYPE T, 
         PROPERTY P, 
         CUSTOMER C, 
         LISTINGS L  
    WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID(+)
    AND   L.SELLER_ID = C.SELLER_ID(+)
    AND   L.PTY_ID = P.PTY_ID(+)
    ORDER BY P.PTY_ID;
```

In nutshell what I want to achieve is to show the property details, listings information (prices, availability) and customer name all together in a single table. The query works perfectly in SQL developer and gave me the results I wanted, but it is not working in my PHP file and gave me no results but blank.

In order to debug I used another set of data and put in and it worked fine as well. Therefore I can tell the PHP codes are cool and go back to the query. But I can't find any problem in it. Can anyone help me? Did I use the join statements wrongly?

I just add my PHP code below in case you might be interested in it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head><title>Update/Delete Property</title></head>
<body>

<center><h2>Property Records</h2></center>

<?php
$conn = oci_connect("username","password","database");

$query = "SELECT P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE, P.PTY_SUBURB, P.PTY_CITY, T.P_TYPE_NAME,
                  L.LIST_PRICE, L.SALE_PRICE,
                  U.SELLER_FNAME, U.SELLER_LNAME, 
                  L.AVAILABILITY

          FROM PROPERTY_TYPE T, PROPERTY P, CUSTOMER C, LISTINGS L  
          WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID(+)
          AND   L.SELLER_ID = U.SELLER_ID(+)
          AND   L.PTY_ID = P.PTY_ID(+)
          ORDER BY P.PTY_ID";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn,$query);
oci_execute($stmt);
?>

<table border="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Property ID</th>
        <th><b>Unit Number</th>
        <th><b>Street</th>
        <th><b>Postcode</th>
        <th><b>Suburb</th>
        <th><b>City</th>
        <th><b>Property Type</th>
        <th><b>Listing Price</th>
        <th><b>Sale Price</th>
        <th colspan = '2'><b>Seller Name</th>
        <th><b>Availability</th>
        <th><b>Checkbox</th>
    </tr>


    <?php
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"PTY_ID");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"PTY_UNITNUM");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"PTY_STREET");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"PTY_POSTCODE");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"PTY_SUBURB");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"PTY_CITY");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"P_TYPE_NAME");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"LIST_PRICE");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"SALE_PRICE");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"SELLER_FNAME");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"SELLER_LNAME");?></td>
        <td><?php echo oci_result($stmt,"AVAILABILITY");?></td>

    </tr>
        <?php
        }
    oci_free_statement($stmt);
    oci_close($conn);
        ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

## The query in this PHP code is similar so I did not change it. It was not running properly as well.

## NEW PROGRESS..

So I tried to change one line of the code:

```
AND   P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID(+)
```

I started to get something...But still not what I wanted:
[New result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phs63.png)

I am pretty sure it's about the query now and it's something about the connection between entities. SO again I am sending up my ERD here, which might help (focus on table LISTINGS, SELLER (**which is called CUSTOMER now**) and PROPERTY):
[ERD of the entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI6eA.png)

Comment: How are you making the query? PDO? Are there any BLOBs or CLOBs in your results? What version of PHP?

Comment: I neither use PDO nor wrote any of those. The PHP version is 5.5.16.@RobWood

Comment: You have a PHP problem, it might help to know what PHP is doing. Maybe add that code? And you sure you're not using the PHP PDO driver for Oracle?

Comment: I was told by my tutor PDO for oracle is outdated so I did not use it..I will upload my PHP code if you want. But I am pretty sure it's fine.@RobWood

Comment: PDO IS buggy, that's why I asked. It's also easier, so commonly used. It sounds like your issue isn't Oracle, it's PHP having a problem with your specific query. Without more info, I can't help much. I'd like to see the code, at least the lines that run the query, and maybe your error.log?

Comment: By the way, if it IS "fine," what are you asking about? Logic says you can't be asking for help in here AND have fine code. Computer science is basically logic.

Comment: I have uploaded the PHP to give you a better picture. @RobWood Might be my mistakes in PHP :P I can't really tell because there is not obvious error

Comment: Anything getting populated in oci_error()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-error.php

OBSCURE YOUR CONNECTION CREDS!!!

Comment: yeah thanks just realised that :P Done and will keep that in mind. And I don't have any error popped up.. I mean the code ran smoothly, however not providing the desired outcome

Comment: Look at the code in the PHP manual link, add oci_error() stuff, check if it is empty or not... Example #3 looks like what you want to look at.
so replace your execute statement with this:

$r = oci_execute($stmt);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stmt);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    print "\n<pre>\n";
    print htmlentities($e['sqltext']);
    printf("\n%".($e['offset']+1)."s", "^");
    print  "\n</pre>\n";
}

Comment: So, the oci_error had something? =} I can't sit here refreshing this page all night. =}

Comment: @RobWood I am sorry my friend I forgot to commit the data to my database... Sorry for wasting your time and truly thanks for your patience

Comment: Ha. Yep, that can be a problem. Glad ya found the issue.